# How to change ip-user agent or proxy in php hosting?

Tags: php, facebook, curl

Using the simple php curl function for Facebook user-account control, I pull out the site and do the detection according to the incoming data.

But because I have multiple queries, Facebook blocks and php codes are disabled. How can I show each browser function as if it was entered from a different computer by modifying the browser ip-user agent (if there is a proxy) before running it?

Thank you.

Comment: In my opinion IP spoofing is a questionable practice at best and I don't think it should be necessary other than for experimenting or testing so it would be good to explain in much more detail what you're trying to do and why the facebook API (which is what you should be using) does not suffice for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to ask that your ip is blocked to get data through API so that you are trying to fetch data from different ip[proxy]. If this is your concern then try to find why your ip has blocked and get whitelist your ip from FB!!!!!

First, access canhazip.com or jsonip.com from the server to make sure it has the public IP you think.

Second, make sure that IP address is in "Server IP Whitelist" for the app's Settings > Advanced section in the Developer console (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[APP ID]/settings/advanced/).

Comment: This [Link](https://www.simplycast.com/interactive-marketing-support/faqs/how-can-i-find-out-if-my-ip-address-has-been-blacklisted/#contact) might also use to check